# GKE ingress resources are not working. getting 404 error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I created ingress resource but it is not working.
Please note - I have not deployed the ingress controller using gke default ( is this mandatory to deploy ingress controller in managed gke )

## I have created two nginx deployment and  nodeport service respectively
here is kubectl get all

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/app1-57df48bcd9-d48l9   1/1     Running   0          69m
pod/app2-8478484c64-khn5w   1/1     Running   0          69m
pod/test-d4df74fc9-kkzjd    1/1     Running   0          42m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/app1         NodePort    10.121.13.120   <none>        8080:32252/TCP   67m
service/app2         NodePort    10.121.15.112   <none>        80:31412/TCP     58m
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.121.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          79m
service/test         NodePort    10.121.13.108   <none>        6060:32493/TCP   42m

NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/app1   1/1     1            1           69m
deployment.apps/app2   1/1     1            1           69m
deployment.apps/test   1/1     1            1           42m

NAME                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/app1-57df48bcd9   1         1         1       69m
replicaset.apps/app2-8478484c64   1         1         1       69m
replicaset.apps/test-d4df74fc9    1         1         1       42m
```

=========================

### and deployed ingress resource as per below
yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: connection
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
```

Ingress description

```
Name:             connection
Namespace:        default
Address:          xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.56.0.9:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /       app1:8080 (10.56.2.4:80)
              /app2   app2:80 (10.56.1.4:80)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:
                {"k8s-be-31412--b52155807170af3c":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32252--b52155807170af3c":"HEALTHY","k8s-be-32504--b52155807170af3c":"HEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s-fw-default-connection--b52155807170af3c
              ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s-tp-default-connection--b52155807170af3c
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s-um-default-connection--b52155807170af3c
              ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Normal  ADD     58m   loadbalancer-controller  default/connection
  Normal  CREATE  57m   loadbalancer-controller  ip: xxxxxxxxxx
```

when I am trying to access `http://ingresLBip/app1` or `http://ingessLBip/app2` I am getting 404 not found error

if I configure ingres resouce with single backend then it is working for single service.

Is anyone face this issue on gke?
do i need to install nginx controller as well?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your applications are listening to `/` and not `/app1` or `/app2` paths. That would explain why the single backend is working. There [seems](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109) to be a limitation in `gce-ingress` controller that it doesn't support `rewrite-target` annotation. If that thread is current then either you have to update the applications to work with the paths or you will have to ditch `gce-ingress` and use `nginx-ingress`.

Comment: Ok./app1 and /app2 both are the different services running in nodeport type..in this case I will use nginx-ingress then...thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use nginx ingress because support for [rewrite-target](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109) annotation in GKE ingress is not there yet.

Install nginx ingress following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke). Change the ingress resource as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: connection
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this happen through classic load balencer, as long as endpoint exists like /app1 and /app2 in your deployed app.

You cannot use GKE ingress instead, you will need to use a classic load balancer with Standalone NEGs with backend.

It is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg#how_to)

Here are the things -

1. Make sure your services uses standalone NEG's.
2. Make sure to pass helthcheck with the endpoints.